# Proper way to backup my Azure VM?

Tags: azure, backup

I need to backup atleast 4 VM's I have on the Azure platform. Each are for different companies but, I have to provide weekly backups. Should I purchase disk space and attach each VM to this disk space to back them up to? At this point the other companies have access to the other companies backup. Do I have to create disk space for each company, connect the server to this disk and backup to that?

Here are my issues, how can I get this done immediately?

Comment: This really is a serverfault question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are following the best practice strategy of: NOT installing anything on the OS or temporary drive (since those get wiped each time the server reprovisioned/redeployed/gets moved in the rack of the datacenter), all you need to worry about is your data disks.

Data disks in Azure use Azure Blob Storage (VHDs), therefore you can use a free tool like CloudXplorer (http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer) and log into your storage account and make a copy of the VHD...as a best practice to another blob storage account in a different region.

You can automate this, by using PowerShell API and copy the VHDs to another storage account/ftp site etc.

Comment: By doing that I am moving the data to another vendor at that poitn correct? Also, I will have to pay MS Azure for the bandwidth of moving the data (approx 50 gigs). How could I do this all within Azure?

Comment: No...any storage transfer within the Microsoft Azure data centers do not get charged.  You will get charged storage of the data though (i.e. a 30 gig VHD).  CloudXPlorer is just a UI tool for the REST APIs provided by Azure, so that is not another storage vendor..just a UI tool like the management portal is.

Answer (score 0):

Azure now how more robust solutions for backing up VMs on Azure, directly within Azure. You can find out more at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/backup/